# SpringFramework and DbUnit integration test class not found AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect Java

Tags: java, spring

I write this integration test but i can not handle the exceptions. The stack trace shows me that the applicationContext can not be found and AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.class can not be found.

**TestController**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:test/test/loginController/LoginControllerTest2-context.xml" })
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@DatabaseSetup("login.xml")
public class LoginControllerTest2 {

    private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:h2:mem:login;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1";
    private static final String USER = "sa";
    private static final String PASS = "";
    private static final String SCHEMA_FILE = "h2.sql";
    private static final String DATASET = "login.xml";

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Resource
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void createSchema() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        try {
            Connection conn = dataSource().getConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(LoginControllerTest2.class.getResourceAsStream(SCHEMA_FILE));
            RunScript.execute(conn, in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    @Before
    public void loadTestData() throws Exception {
        // mockMvc =
        // MockMvcBuilders.xmlConfigSetup("classpath:LoginControllerTest2-context.xml").build();

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webApplicationContextSetup(wac).build();

        // mockMvc =
        // MockMvcBuilders.annotationConfigSetup(LoginControllerTest2.class).build();

        IDataSet ids = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(LoginControllerTest2.class.getResourceAsStream(DATASET));
        JdbcDatabaseTester databaseTester = new JdbcDatabaseTester(JDBC_DRIVER, JDBC_URL, USER, PASS);
        databaseTester.setSetUpOperation(org.dbunit.operation.DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT);
        databaseTester.setDataSet(ids);
        databaseTester.onSetup();
    }

    private static DataSource dataSource() {
        JdbcDataSource dataSource = new JdbcDataSource();
        dataSource.setURL(JDBC_URL);
        dataSource.setUser(USER);
        dataSource.setPassword(PASS);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Test
    @ExpectedDatabase("login.xml")
    public void testShowForm() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/login")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("/login"))
                .andExpect(forwardedUrl("../../WebContent/j/login.jsp"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("passportId", nullValue())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("email", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("username", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("hostname", isEmptyOrNullString())))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("form", hasProperty("pass", isEmptyOrNullString())));
    }

}
```

**application context**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="test.loginController" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:spring-configured />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
                <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver" />
                <property name="url"
                    value="jdbc:h2:mem:login;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=2;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4" />
                <property name="username" value="sa" />
                <property name="password" value="" />
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="test/test/loginController/h2.sql" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

</beans>
```

**stack trace**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect] for bean with name 'org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect' defined in null; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect] for bean with name 'org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect' defined in null; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect] for bean with name 'org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect' defined in null; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:665)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:621)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:398)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:139)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1320)
    ... 54 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you miss the `spring-aspects.jar`  as a dependency in your Project.
Add to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, i know that. Abdelhak above said the same.

Comment: @RockOrDead Then try it and it helps upvote the answers and accept one of them

Comment: I added that jar before i post question here and this is not the solution.

Comment: @RockOrDead you are sure that you have the `spring-aspects.jar` in your classpath at runtime?

Comment: i run the test with F11 in Eclipse

Comment: You are run it in eclipse?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103101/discussion-between-jens-and-rockordead).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this `spring-aspects` dependency like this:

```
<dependency> 
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
 <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: I do not use maven but i added **spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar** which i think is the same but still i have this exceptions.